# convert dataframe column into int so can sort and do calulations on the column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe row as such like below

```
a     |  b                 | c     |  d
1     |-700.5;-1000.0;200.0|  yes  | blue
```

I want to change column b to be numeric so I can do data work like sorting on it but when I try the below code

```
df= pd.to_numeric(df["b"])
print(df)
```

Get error ValueError: Unable to parse string or issue with "-".

Comment: What number is `-700.5;-1000.0;200` expected to convert to?

Comment: so have -1000,-700.5,200 as such so can do calculations with the values etc

Comment: Are you expecting to have the row the same, but have a _list_ of numeric values in the same position, or to `explode` the elements into multiple rows? It would help to see an example of the calculation you intend to do, or your expected output

Comment: How would you sort on `-1000,-700.5,200`?

Comment: is it not possible to sort the series of strings into numeric values so can sort them on the one row as such

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
df.assign(b = df.b.str.split(';')).explode('b')
```

Output:

```
   a        b    c     d
0  1   -700.5  yes  blue
0  1  -1000.0  yes  blue
0  1    200.0  yes  blue
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need that in the same column?

here is one way to do it

```
# split, and sort then join back

df['b'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x:  sorted([(float(i)) for i in x], reverse=True))
```

```
df['b']=df['b'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x:  sorted([(float(i)) for i in x], reverse=True)) 
df
```

```
    a   b                           c       d
0   1   [200.0, -700.5, -1000.0]    yes     blue
```